# NestJs: DTO showing all query parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, nestjs, dto

I'm trying to use 2 separate dto for query parameters in NestJs. However, on printing both dtos are showing same properties. Is there any way to separate them.

// dto code

```
export class PageDto {
  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  page: number;

  @Type(() => Number)
  @IsInt()
  limit: number;
}

export class MyDto {
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  status: string;

  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  source: string;
}
```

Api request:

> GET url?page=1&limit=10&status='active'&source='firebase'

controller:

```
@Get()
  async get(
    @Query() myDto: MyDto,
    @Query() pageDto: PageDto,
  ) {
     console.log({pageDto}, {myDto});
  }
```

Console statement prints:

```
{
   pageDto: {
    page: 1,
    limit: 10,
    status: 'active',
    source: 'firebase'
   }
}

{
   myDto: {
    page: 1,
    limit: 10,
    status: 'active',
    source: 'firebase'
   }
}
```

Required:

```
{
   pageDto: {
    page: 1,
    limit: 10
   }
}

{
   myDto: {
    status: 'active',
    source: 'firebase'
   }
}
```

Ideally, pageDto and myDto should show their respective properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to set `whitelist: true` in your `ValidationPipe` options to tell `class-transformer` and `class-validator` to strip out the properties that don't exist on the DTO.

[Reference to the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation#using-the-built-in-validationpipe)